# How does the Ethereal's damage reflection work?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

The Ethereal alien species has a rather annoying habit of blocking and reflecting shots fired by my soldiers. I expected to gleam some insight as to how this ability works after performing an autopsy on one, but was rather surprised not to see anything related to this ability when examining an Ethereal in the unit analysis view (it had quite a few abilities though, so it's possible, though improbable, that I missed the description despite looking for it).

So how does this ability work? Is it related to the range at which the shot is taken (I've never seen them block a sniper's shot)? Is there simply some random percentage for a shot to be blocked? Is flanking a factor?

Comment: Pretty sure I've had a sniper shot blocked before.

Comment: yeah, I've had sniper shots blocked, but never reflected towards the sniper. Which would indicate there is maximum range to that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my experience it seems to be a random chance to block all shots. But I am not able to tell you the exact % - I estimate it is around 20% from my own experience.

I have had the following shots blocked:

- 100% chance to hit flanked shotgun at point blank range
- Sniper 'headshot' from a long range and a normal sniper shot
- Normal shots

I have also seen the reflection

- On the first shot fired at him
- On full health
- On 1 health
- On half health
- On the 2nd,3rd and 4th shot fired at him (all in the same turn - i.e. he can do it more than once a turn)

What I have NEVER seen "reflected" is rocket and grenade damage. So if the Ethereal is on low HP - it might be better to kill him this way to guarantee yourself the kill.
Likewise (if riskier), it can't block the Arc Thrower, and the upgraded one has a high chance of a stun on 6 health and below.

Comment: An arc thrower could also do the job on a low health Ethereal.

Comment: Are you sure the 100% chance to hit shot was reflected? I've heard rumblings that they can only reflect missed shots.

Comment: It was a shotgun, at point blank range, as a flank. I'm certain it was 100% to hit - but I'll try and do a test to confirm

Comment: @RavenDreamer - fyi - I can now confirm shots against Ethereals can "miss", "hit" and "reflect". So its not just 'missed' shots that reflect.

Comment: IIRC (not sure) I got reflected headshot (from plasma sniper, ouch). And what I seen was block of reflections followed by not reflecting at all. So maybe its some ammount of damage it prevents?

Comment: @user470365 - the shot is either a "hit" (and does normal damage), a "miss" (and does nothing) or a "reflect" (and does 0 damage to enemy, but reflects some damage back to the solider, usually doing 2 dmg)

Comment: One good thing - I didn't see them reflect greanade :D

Comment: "On low HP"? The Blaster Launcher with Mayhem does 12 damage. That's half its health. Fusion Cores are always acquired in pairs, and there's a max of one ethereal per level (except for the final level), so just bring two heavies (12+9>20, so only one needs to have Mayhem) and you've got yourself a legitimate strategy.